# USBView/ Device manager in python

Tags: python, cmd

How can I access Device Manager in python, so that i can get the usb device's serial number/other info through python?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the Device Manager (A *graphical* application), you can *programmatically* access information about USB devices via [PyUSB](https://github.com/walac/pyusb):

```
import usb.core
allDevs = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
```

Now, iterate over `allDevs` to get information about connected devices.